# Keeping button in same position with all different screen resolutions

Tags: android, css

I'm trying to keep my button in the same position for for all screen resolutions, tablet, mobile, desktop, and larger screens. How do I do this?

```
#scrollmorebutton {
    background: url('/assets/images/ui-s3b4cd44ffb.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    height: 55px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 504px;
    width: 55px;
    left: 650px;
}
```

Comment: judging by your css rules it looks like your button is already fixed to `504px` to the top and `650px` to the left. Why don't you explain what's wrong with it or simply put a snippet or fiddle to help you

Comment: Could we get a fiddle or codepen with your code? Having a defined, fixed position should keep it in place, so we might need to find a new problem. For example, is it wrapped in a div without a fixed position? Or have you tried wrapping it in a div with a fixed position?